# JPA: Many to Many filter query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a many to many relationship between a Cluster and Tag table using an another intermediate table ClusterTag. Below, I have the bidirectional mapping.

I need help with coming up with a query (JPA/HIBERNATE) for the scenario where users can specify multiple (TagName and TagValue) combinations, and I have to retrieve only those Clusters which have ALL those combination of TagName and TagValues associated with them   like WHERE (tagName=? AND tagValue=?) AND (tagName=? AND tagValue=?) ........

```
 @Entity(name = “Cluster”)
    @Table(name = “cluster”)
    public class ClusterDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3501772243949297059L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "mapped_id", nullable = false)
    private String mappedId;

    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "last_update", nullable = false)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updateTimestamp;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "cluster",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ClusterTagDto> tags = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addTag(TagDto tag) {
        ClusterTagDto clusterTag = new ClusterTagDto(this, tag);
        tags.add(clusterTag);
        tag.getClusters().add(clusterTag);
    }


    public void removeTag(TagDto tag) {
        for (Iterator<ClusterTagDto> iterator = tags.iterator();
             iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            ClusterTagDto clusterTag = iterator.next();

            if (clusterTag.getCluster().equals(this) &&
                clusterTag.getTag().equals(tag)) {
                iterator.remove();
                clusterTag.getTag().getClusters().remove(clusterTag);
                clusterTag.setCluster(null);
                clusterTag.setTag(null);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ClusterDto))
            return false;
        ClusterDto that = (ClusterDto) o;
        return Objects.equals(uuid, that.uuid);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(uuid);
    }
    }



    @Entity(name = “ClusterTag”)
    @Table(name = “cluster_tag”)
    public class ClusterTagDto {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClusterTagId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("clusterId")
    private ClusterDto cluster;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("tagId")
    private TagDto tag;

    @Column(name="create_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createTimestamp;

    @Column(name="last_update", nullable = false)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updateTimestamp;

    private ClusterTagDto() {}

    public ClusterTagDto(ClusterDto cluster, TagDto tag) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.id = new ClusterTagId(cluster.getId(), tag.getId());
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ClusterTagDto))
            return false;
        ClusterTagDto that = (ClusterTagDto) o;
        return Objects.equals(cluster, that.cluster) &&
            Objects.equals(tag, that.tag);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(cluster, tag);
    }
    }


    @Entity(name = “ClusterTag”)
    @Table(name = “tag”)
    public class TagDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3501772243949297059L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "tag_name", nullable = false)
    private String tagName;

    @Column(name = "tag_value", nullable = false)
    private String tagValue;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "tag",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ClusterTagDto> clusters = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof TagDto))
            return false;
        TagDto tagDto = (TagDto) o;
        return Objects.equals(uuid, tagDto.uuid);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(uuid);
    }
    }
```

regards
aravias

Comment: Isnt simple join enough?

Comment: *WHERE (tagName=? AND tagValue=?) AND (tagName=? AND tagValue=?)* I think you meant `() OR ()` not `AND`

Comment: I meant AND , for an OR    a simple join will work from what I tried , but for AND i am not sure its just a simple join unless i overlooked something

Comment: the tagname and tagvalues  could be like  tagName spark and its TagValue 2.3, then another tagName   hadoop and its tagValue 2.7 , and I want to select all clusters which have both of those.

Comment: But if you use AND then it wont work as tag value cannot be x and y @ the same time. Its effectively WHERE `tagName=x AND tagV=xv AND tagName=y and tagV=yv` - whis will be false always

Comment: yeah,  i was thinking it has to be multiple queries to solve this, and would like to get some thoughts on how to go about that.

Comment: Just use OR - `tagName=x AND tagv=xv OR tagName=y AND tagName=yv` cuz you want this pair OR that pair OR.... any other pair

Comment: but that might also return me clusters which just  have any one of those combinations like spark 2.3 or hadoop 2.7 ,and not always both of them ?

Comment: no if you limit to particular cluster.... its WHERE cluster like this AND (tag like this OR like this OR like that )

Comment: i think i need to understand a bit more of what u are suggesting when u say  limit to a particular cluster

Comment: I think you need to understand basis of sql JOIN

Comment: select c from Cluster c JOIN ClusterTag ct ON c.id = ct.id.clusterId JOIN Tag t ON ct.id.tagId = t.id WHERE (t.tagName=x AND t.tagValue=xv) OR (t.tagName=y AND t.tagValue=yv)           can u modify above if it is different from what you have suggested.

Comment: i guess i was not very clear in explaining my  use case, there is an example here why the OR is not sufficient   https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-fetch-one-side-of-a-many-to-many-association-while-filtering-the-other-using-hibernate/1095/6

Comment: U can either INNER JOIN cluster multiple times with tags or use multiple EXISTS clauses

Comment: a solution using exists clause here   https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-fetch-one-side-of-a-many-to-many-association-while-on-the-other-side-all-records-match-a-given-filtering-criteria/1095